# Domain user not having admin rights on local machine

Tags: windows-7, windows, administrator, domain, local

I'm using Windows 2003 server as active directory and Windows 7 as a station. I need to have a regular domain user have admin rights on local machine. I added domain user to local admin group but they still do not have full access as local administrator.

Comment: Just to confirm, the Windows 7 machine is joined to the domain.  Yes?

Comment: Yes it is, in fact domain admins belong to local admin group, I just added a regular domain user to local admin group but still no rights on local machine

Comment: And you're positive that it was the domain user that got added and not a local user with the same name? (sorry, just trying to run through the obvious things! :)  Do you see it listed in the Administrators group on the PC?

Comment: Curious. Also what action are you using to "test" that the user has full access as local administrator?

Comment: I just disabled UAC and now it works!

Answer (score 8):

On the workstation log in as domain admin and issue

```
net localgroup Administrators /add DOMAIN\USER
```

That will make the domain user an Administrator on that workstation only.

Comment: I'm assuming that's what the OP did when he said, " I added domain user to local admin group . . ."  If not, then that's our problem.

Comment: thanks! I logged in as local admin and ran it on my domain account and it worked.